# C++ Primer Exercise 2.25

Tags: c++

on C++ Primer 5th edition book there is an exercise (2.25) that I can't figure out.

> Exercise 2.25: Determine the types and values of each of the following
>   variables.
>   `(a) int* ip, &r = ip;`

Now, the book makes this example:

```
int i = 42;
int *p; // p is a pointer to int
int *&r = p; // r is a reference to the pointer p
```

So, my question is, why in that exercise the &r has not the * operator? Is there any difference writing

```
int *&r = ip;
```

or

```
int &r = ip;
```

(where ip is a pointer to int)

?

Comment: This `int* ip, &r = ip;` is an invalid declaration. Was it the intent of the book to present the reader with an invalid declaration? Or is it just an error in the book?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the author of that book thought that the signature `int*` would carry out to all of the comma-separate variable declarations, making `r` a reference to pointer. Indeed [the code does not compile](http://rextester.com/LPQUOF85501) because this is not true. `ip` is declared as a pointer to an `int` and `r` is only declared as a reference to an `int`.

The compiler interprets

```c++
int * ip, &r = ip;
```

equivalently to

```c++
int * ip;
int & r = ip; // won't compile
```

You need an extra `*` to declare it as a reference to pointer type:

```c++
int *op, *&r = ip;
```

You can also use a `typedef`:

```c++
typedef int* IntPtr;
IntPtr op, &r = ip;
```

Answer (score 7):

You're very right to be confused.

I found [the errata page](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321714114/errata/9780321714114_errata_10-31-12.html), and it states

> Page 59: Exercise 2.25 (a) should be int* ip, i, &r = i;

which makes a whole lot more sense.

(This should probably be a comment, but it's easier to read here...)